# Controlar AutoPostback de un botón

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

No se como hacer para controlar el `AutoPostback` desde `Javascript` que genera un botón de ASP.NET.

```
<asp:Button ID="boton" runat="server" OnClick="re_Click" OnClientClick="prueba()" style="height: 32px" Text="enviar" />"
```

Lo que busco es lo siguiente:

Tengo un control `Textbox` que cuando su valor diga "hola" al hacer click en el botón quiero que todavía no se haga `Postback` y simplemente inserte una etiqueta `span` con cualquier texto; pero si su valor diga "adios" al hacer click en el botón quiero que desaparezca la etiqueta `span` y haga `Postback`.

Answer (score 2):

Usa preventDefault de Jquery:

```js
    $("#form").submit(function(evento){
        if($("#text").val() == "hola"){
           evento.preventDefault();
           alert("Cualquier cosa");
        }else{
           //Se envia formulario.
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="#" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="texto">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero me sigue haciendo postback ingrese el texto que ingrese :/ Ah, se me olvido algo, el boton es de asp! por que tambien necesito modificar algo desde el Onclick. Sera editar mi pregunta para agregar ese pequeño detalle :v

Comment: Intenta en vez de "evento.preventDefault(); con "return false;"

Comment: Claro, el "return false;" deshabilita el postback, de ahi me diste una idea. Pero creo que desde jquery no se esta tomando el valor del textbox, como que lo ignora. Incluso lo cambie a javascript porque me siento mas comodo asi pero nada. Te voy a pasar el codigo para que me orientes y me ayudes a encontrar ahi la falla. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

El siguiente código está basado en esta [respuesta en Stack Overflow en Inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15215645/4092887):

---

Puedes usar dos botones *(uno oculto y otro visible)*.

El botón visible llamado "BtnPrueba" tendrá esta estructura y se encargará de llamar a la función de javascript `prueba();`:

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnPrueba" runat="server" OnClientClick="prueba();" style="height: 32px" Text="enviar" />"
```

Tu función `prueba();` tendrá lo siguiente:

```
function prueba() {
    var texto = document.getElementById('text').value;

    switch (texto) {
        case "hola":
            // Mostrar un texto predeterminado en un span.
            document.getElementById('mySpan').value = "No se activa el postback...";
            break;

        case "adios":
            // Ocultar el span.
            document.getElementById('mySpan').setAttribute("style" , "display: none;");
            document.getElementById('mySpan').value = "";

            // Llamar al evento onclick del botón oculto.
            document.getElementById('<%= BtnEnviar.ClientID %>').click();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Mientras que tu botón oculto "BtnEnviar" tendrá esta estructura:

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnEnviar" runat="server" OnClick="BtnEnviar_Click" style="height: 32px" Text="Enviar" style="display:none" />"
```

Comment: Mil gracias por responder, de verdad, aprecio mucho los aportes de todos ustedes. Pero en la gran mayoria de las veces siempre termino resolviendo las cosas con un machetazo impresionante :v Siempre termino complicando las cosas y haciendo todo por el camino "mas dificil"; añadiendo mas controles, mas procesos, y siempre por desconocimiento de la documentacion.Si puediera marcar todas estos aportes como utiles, lo haria, porque en verdad me encaminaron a la solucion, pero la reputacion no deja :v En fin, nuevamente muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Si estás usando ASP.Net webforms y sus controles yo usaría un "**CustomValidator**".

No porque tenga nada en contra de jquery, es porque la realidad tienes herramientas dentro de ASP.Net webcontrols que te pueden ayudar.

En primer lugar no tienes un problema de autopostback. Lo tendrías si no tuvieras el botón submit y pusieras autopostback="true" en el textbox (que no es el caso).

Para "Anular" el botón de submit te recomiendo simplemente valides el campo texbox con un Customvalidator. 
**args.isValid** hará el trabajo de anular el postback.

```
<asp:Textbox id="text1" runat="server" text=""></asp:Textbox>
<asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator2" runat="server" 
  ControlToValidate = "text1"
  ErrorMessage = "Introduce cualquier cosa menos HOLA!"
  ClientValidationFunction="valida" >
</asp:CustomValidator>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function valida(oSrc, args){
   args.IsValid = /*tu validación*/;
}
</script>
```

Para mostrar un mensaje de error al usuario puedes usar **"ValidationSummary"**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd5c6s6h(v=vs.71).aspx